# In Safari, why are the vote up and vote down arrows and the accept answer button invisible for me on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, bug, design

[image: another random stackoverflow.com screenshot. Note the missing vote arrows. This is after clearing Safari cache. This same page loads fine in Chrome.][image: No vote buttons]

I downloaded Chrome and it works fine.  So real question should be , why does it not work in Safari?  I cleared the cache and cookies and this still does not fix the Safari issue. I am running a new Mac Book Air (latest model) with latest version of Safari (Version 8.0.2 (10600.2.5) )

I am using Safari on a MacBook Air, and for every answer someone posts to my question, the accept answer button and voting arrows are invisible. The only way to accept an answer in Safari (for me) is to blindly click an invisible area below the answerer's vote number.

I don't have this problem in Safari for meta.SE  Math.SE and Puzzling.SE , so I know it is a problem unique to www.stackoverflow.com and not meta.stackoverflow.com or other Stack Exchange sites.

Again this problem is only on Stack Overflow and not on the other Stack Exchange websites.

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot of what you do see? Is the issue reproducible on Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Safari: http://i.stack.imgur.com/85qqq.png, nor on Chrome (http://i.stack.imgur.com/TDPWZ.png) or Firefox (looks the same, didn't bother with a screenshot). All on OS X 10.10.2.

Comment: The accept checkmark isn't hidden for low-rep users either; the big V mark is *always* present when you are looking at answers to your own questions. Are you sure you are *logged in*?

Comment: i posted the screenshot ..  there is no accept answer button on any of my questions to this site.

Comment: You have no voting buttons either; looks like the CSS sprite has failed to load. Can you do a force reload? (Shift-click the reload icon). If that fails, clear your cache and load again.

Comment: that doesn't work, but I will try shutting down safari and opening it again

Comment: i restarted safari, and problem is still there.  reloading doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: it works fine on math.stackoverflow.com and puzzling.stackoverflow.com so makes me feel it is a problem only with www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: i deleted the 2nd image because it was a duplicate of the first

Comment: The problem is limited to just you, this is not normal behaviour.. Are there any extensions active? You may have to clear all cached data; Preferences -> Privacy -> Remove All Website Data.

Comment: Check Safari's Network console - do you see an error for `http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg`?

Comment: this problem not only is for accepting an answer.. all upvote arrows and down vote arrow for every question on www.stackoverflow.com 's website is missing for a low rep user.   But the other stackoverflow sites work fine, like meta.stackoverflow works fine , for example

Comment: Also, can you load http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg directly?

Comment: @MichaelRize: no, those are visible to **all** users, the error is *local to your browser*.

Comment: "This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty"  when I load sprites.svg .  I think the problem is bigger than you think martijin

Comment: @MichaelRize; the CSS sprite image has failed to load for you, so you wont see badge icons either (round circles in bronze, silver and gold), and the favorite star on questions will also not show.

Comment: i can see these things on the other stack overflow sites,   only www.stackoverflow.com has the problem

Comment: @MichaelRize: the image loads fine anywhere else. You appear to have a network problem.

Comment: ok, then my network problem affects not only my browser, so your previous statement was wrong.

Comment: There could be a problem with some node in the CDN, and if others see it they may find this meta question. I can't reproduce though.

Comment: And since you can't load `sprites.svg` directly, it has nothing to do with reputation. That's a static image file available to anyone.

Comment: @MichaelRize: Note that I am trying to *help* you; why the focus on wether or not I am wrong or right here?

Comment: is the "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg" url used for all stackoverflow sites, or only for www.stackoverflow.com ?  because the sprites load correctly on the other sites, just fine.

Comment: also, I am presently in the Philippines , so if it is a problem with the network, maybe this will help localize it.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes, also a possibility there. Hard to distinguish that from a network problem though.

Comment: Martjin, I made that comment because assuming it is only my problem (without evidence) is not helpful, and in fact can be offensive.

Comment: @MichaelRize it is the Stack Overflow specific version. What happens when you add `?_=abcd` to the url?

Comment: I get the same error : "This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error."

Comment: when I try "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?_=abcd"

Comment: I am downloading Chrome now to see if the result is the duplicated with a different browser.

Comment: it works fine in Chrome..  and the url loads properly.  So real question should be, why doesn't it work in Safari, and what do I need to do?  clear the Safari cache?

Comment: I cleared all website data including all cache and cookies..  and the problem is still there (for Safari)  ..  It would not let me comment without logging in again, because the cookie was gone, so I know the cache was cleared.  Odd problem.  Why would it work in Chrome but not in Safari, if it is not an issue with the cache?

Comment: restarted Safari as well, same problem.  Makes me lose all confidence in Safari as a browser.  Will be using only Chrome from now on.

Comment: Cookies and image cache are entirely different things, so having to log in again doesn't prove anything.

Comment: @MichaelRize which version of Safari are you using?  If it is too old or a beta, it might not be supported.

Comment: I cleared all browsing data in Safari.  I am using the newest Mac Book Air, with the latest version of Safari.   Works fine on meta.stackoverflow.com and math.stackoverflow.com and puzzling.stackoverflow.com.  Only with www.stackoverflow.com is there this problem, and only with Safari.  Works fine in Chrome.  My Safari version is Version 8.0.2 (10600.2.5)

Comment: Can you use the Safari developer tools to inspect the elements and see why they do not display?

Comment: I don't believe I have Safari developer tools installed.  If they are installed by default, where do I find them?  Thanks

Comment: They are disabled by default, [see these instructions to enable](http://debugbrowser.com/).

Comment: i enabled the developer tools, and trying out the web inspector.  Not exactly sure what I am looking for, but I will try.

Comment: "a.vote-up-off" , "a.vote-down-off" and  "a.star-off" are the class (s) not displaying on every question.  Not sure what are the image names.  Trying to find more information than that, but it is my first time using the Safari inspector

Comment: Any suggestion on how I should use the the developer tools to find out why the elements do not display?  I searched and cannot find image names when I use the inspector and hover over the relevant elements.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use https? [https://stackoverflow.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: I just tried https://stackoverflow.com and have the same problem. (https)

Comment: I've been having the same problem (Firefox). To reproduce:
1. Find a stackoverflow topic on google
2. You will be redirected to http version of stackoverflow
3. In firebug, check the css for the vote buttons, it will show that the image url is http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=1bc6a0c03b68. This url produces "XML Parsing Error: syntax error"
4. Change the url to https instead, then the sprites will work.

So basically, stackoverflow should redirect to the https version of the site and all would be good.